# angular method not firing in controller after service call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a angular service that gets the currentuser object that is resolved as a promise. I have a partial that is filled by an object userdetails which is invoked inside a method call, but unfortunately the method call is not firing when called after the promise is resolved.

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'userService', '$compile', '$http', 'utility', 'cloudService', function ($scope, userService, $compile, $http, utility, cloudService) {

        $scope.userdetails = {};
        $scope.downloadPageChk = $scope.paymentHistoryPageChk = $scope.manageGroupsPageChk = "hide";
        $scope.getUserAttribute = function (param, x) {
            return userService.getAttribute(param, x);
        };
                cloudService.fetchCurrentUser().then(function (newCurrentuser)
                {
                    if (newCurrentuser)
                    {
                        $scope.currentUser = newCurrentuser;
                        $scope.getUserDetails = function()
                        {
                            if (userService && userService.isLoggedIn())
                            {
                                $scope.userdetails = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentUser));
                            }
                        };

                        if (newCurrentuser == 'member') {
                            if (newCurrentuser.features.download) $scope.downloadPageChk = "show";
                            if (newCurrentuser.features.paymenthistory) $scope.paymentHistoryPageChk = "show";
                            if (newCurrentuser.group.enabled) $scope.manageGroupsPageChk = "show";
                        }
                    }
                }
])

partial
 <div data-ng-controller="AccountCtrl">
<div data-ng-init="getUserDetails()">
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" data-placeholder-attr="First Name" data-ng-model="userdetails.firstname" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" id="LastName" name="LastName" data-placeholder-attr="Last Name" data-ng-model="userdetails.lastname" required>
</div>
</div>
```

please do let me know what am I missing. I am banging my head for 10 hours now, if I move user details out if that cloudservice.fetchuser().then() it atleast calls the function, not sure what is happening when i put it inside.

**Similar** plunk created here
http://plnkr.co/edit/pLAB4VpLU7uhlSibHzXP?p=preview
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the function outside the `cloudservice.fetchuser().then()` method. The `getUserDetails` method is not available to the `$scope` object until you call `cloudservice.fetchuser().then()`. But you do not do this in your partial.

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'userService', '$compile', '$http', 'utility', 'cloudService', 
  function ($scope, userService, $compile, $http, utility, cloudService) {
     $scope.userdetails = {};

     $scope.getUserDetails = function(service, user) {
       if (service && service.isLoggedIn()) {
         $scope.userdetails = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
       }
     };

     $scope.downloadPageChk = $scope.paymentHistoryPageChk = $scope.manageGroupsPageChk = "hide";

     $scope.getUserAttribute = function (param, x) {
       return userService.getAttribute(param, x);
     };

     cloudService.fetchCurrentUser().then(function (newCurrentuser) {
       if (newCurrentuser) {
         $scope.currentUser = newCurrentuser;
         $scope.getUserDetails(userService, newCurrentuser);

          if (newCurrentuser == 'member') {
            if (newCurrentuser.features.download) $scope.downloadPageChk = "show";
            if (newCurrentuser.features.paymenthistory) $scope.paymentHistoryPageChk = "show";
            if (newCurrentuser.group.enabled) $scope.manageGroupsPageChk = "show";
          }
       }
     });
   });
]);
```

Comment: No I cannot move the function outside the cloudservice.fetchuser().then() , because the $scope.userdetails object is filled using the newCurrentuser object returned from the service and as it is an async call

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can extract the `getUserDetails` method and call it in the asynchronous `cloudService.fetchCurrentUser.then` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the data to be initializied - you don't need the `$scope.getUserDetails` function and the `data-ng-init="getUserDetails()"`.

Angular will execute the service `fetchCurrentUser` function and will populate `$scope.userdetails` on loading.

```
cloudService.fetchCurrentUser().then(function (newCurrentuser)
{
   if (newCurrentuser)
   {
         $scope.currentUser = newCurrentuser;
         if (userService && userService.isLoggedIn())
         {
            $scope.userdetails = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.currentUser));
         }

         if (newCurrentuser == 'member') {
            if (newCurrentuser.features.download) $scope.downloadPageChk = "show";
            if (newCurrentuser.features.paymenthistory) $scope.paymentHistoryPageChk = "show";
            if (newCurrentuser.group.enabled) $scope.manageGroupsPageChk = "show";
         }
       }
   }
}
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uHDszkK6iKRj2mWE085X?p=preview).

*EDIT*:

If you want the `getUserDetails` function to still be triggerable after initialization you should put it outside the service method:

```
$scope.getUserDetails = function(){
    if (userService && userService.isLoggedIn()){
       $scope.userdetails = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.currentUser));
    }
};
```

And trigger it however you want (via `ng-click="getUserDetails()"` from the view or `$scope.getUserDetails()` from the controller).

Comment: That works..but my problem is..what if I have to execute a method like I am calling on ng-init after the newCurrentuser object is available?

Comment: @skm added explanation to my answer, is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You are running `ng-init` before `$scope.getUserDetails` has been added to `$scope`, because that only happens in the callback, and that's why you are having the problems.

i think you may be following some of the basic examples a little too closely. As you are getting data asynchronously you don't need `ng-init` 
You let you controller ask the service to download the data, and when it has arrived you assign it to `$scope.getUserDetails` and angular will put it on the screen.

You can see the updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GA06Sclh8XGZXgQfmiWq?p=preview)

Let me know if I'm missing something significant

Comment: might mention difference between `success` in demo and `then` in question code. OP treating them the same regarding response

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any use of `ng-init` directive and `$scope.getUserDetails` method, angular two way data binding will handle the promises. I have updated the plunker for same. http://plnkr.co/edit/IzjNqpdk0zvnHYyCnKJi?p=preview